# Elements of quotient group $S_8/D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

> Consider a regular octagon with vertices labeled cyclically. Consider $C_8 \hookrightarrow D_8 \hookrightarrow S_8$, where the copy of $C_8$ is generated by a counterclockwise rotation $r$, the copy of $D_8$ is all the (rigid) symmetries of the octagon, and the symmetric group is given by all the permutations of the labels, whether or not they can be rigidly achieved. 
>   a) What is $|D_8/C_8|$? What does an arbitrary element of $D_8/C_8$ look like? Name two distinct elements. Is $D_8/C_8$ a group? 
>   b) What is $|S_8/D_8|$? What does an arbitrary element of $S_8/D_8$ look like? Name two distinct elements. Is $S_8/D_8$ a group?

**My attempt:** 
a) As I understand $C_8=\{e,r,r^2,...,r^7\}, D_8=\{e,r,r^2,...,r^7,s,sr,...,sr^7\}.$ Then $D_8/C_8=\{C_8, D_8\setminus C_8\},$ so $|D_8/C_8|=2.  D_8\setminus C_8 =sC_8=\{s,sr,...,sr^7\}.$ Next, $D_8/C_8$ is a group if and only if $C_8$ is normal. But I don't know how to prove/disprove that... 
b) I'm completely stuck here. How to write down the cosets of $D_8$ in $S_8$?

Comment: You cannot do a quotient of $S_8$ by $D_8$; the only normal subgroups of $S_8$ are the trivial one, $S_8$, and $A_8$. You can form the set of cosets of $D_8$ in $S_8$ and count them, but you cannot talk about “the quotient group:”.,

Comment: The cosets are written as usual: they are of the form $\sigma D_8$ with $\sigma\in S_8$. And $\sigma D_8 = \tau D_8$ if and only if $\tau^{-1}\sigma\in D_8$. What exactly is your issue with (b)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$C_n$ is a subgroup of $D_n$ of index $2$ for all $n\ge 3$, and hence $C_n$ is a normal subgroup of $D_n$ with $D_n/C_n\cong C_2$. So it has $2$ elements.
The subgroup $D_8$ however is not normal in $S_8$, as mentioned by Arturo, but the quotient set has $\frac{|S_8|}{|D_8|}=8!/16=2520$ elements.